# Will this make changes to "request", in Django?

Tags: python, django, oop

```
# in views.py

def start(request):
    initial_dictionary = {"abc":"abc"}
    request.session['123'] = "xyz"
    return initial_dictionary


def post(request):
    dictionary = start(request)
    return render_to_response("blah")
```

This is OOP.  Will this make changes to "request", and will the session be set? (request is passed as a pointer)

Comment: No, it's passed as a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: Are you sure in this case, it's passed as a reference?

Comment: Well, yes, because Python doesn't *have* pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session object [comes from the `HttpRequest`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views), so if that's what gets passed into the function as `request` then what you have should work.